# Do Zoro, Nami and Robin suffer from bad eyesight?

Tags: one-piece

Although I never noticed in the main story of the anime, there are scenes in some of the openings where Zoro, Nami and Robin are shown wearing eyeglasses:

- [Zoro in opening 11](http://youtu.be/tIPp1Zhg2gU?t=33s)
- [Robin in opening 13](http://youtu.be/ntoB59VttFU?t=55s)
- [Nami in opening 16](http://youtu.be/3wSvrBxzX4o?t=26s)

Is the fact that they all have bad eyesight canon? Or is it just some filler that the author probably wanted to mix into the series?

Comment: Robin and Nami May be.Robin reads lots of book and Name draws maps. But wearing eyeglasses doesn't mean of bad eye sight. It may be for character's looks, appearance.

Comment: In the videos Robin is reading and Nami is charting. they may not have bad eye-sight but they may want their sight enhanced for those tasks. in the video for Zoro he's just lounging about however the glasses may be a throw back to that Marine Swordswoman who was with Smoker who didn't like the fact that a Pirate had a Legendary Sword (or after that, 3) and looked like that swordswoman Zoro admired when he was a kid

Comment: @mirroroftruth I don't recall any character in any series that wear an eyeglasses (**not** sunglasses) just for the sake of appearance.

Comment: `may be for appearance` like appearance while reading. Zorro is reading book and like some people use glasses to reduce the side effect while using computer and other thing which may damage the eye sight.

Answer (score 2):

Considering they don't wear glasses normally or even while reading, it's fair to say that their eyesight is just fine. They simply like to wear those glasses from time to time for the sake of appearance. Even Sanji wore glasses for a moment in One Piece Film Z, for that same reason.

Comment: Do you have any reference that prove it?
How can you know for sure it was for the sake of the appearance alone?

Comment: Not only are there no references that prove that their eyesight is bad either, but if they really did suffer from bad eyesight, they'd wear glasses all the time (like Tashigi does, for example), or at least when working or reading. As far as I know, they don't, and only wear glasses from time to time, which proves that they don't need them.

Comment: Don't forget Sanji wore glasses as "The prince" in Alabasta :P

Answer (score 1):

Well. Guys. I recall Nami wore glasses in Sky Island arc and she was working on the map of the island at that time or something. Therefore I think Nami has and ocasionally wears glasses for her work. For Robin, I think she might also have them because reading so many books.. but I am not sure about her. For Zoro and Sanji, I have a feeling they were more for appearance - like in Film Z, Zoro had glasses and other clothes and Brook commented something like how did he like the way Brook dressed him up xD ok I know it sounds strange but I hope you get what I mean.